# Edit D3 SVG's links position in a "radial" Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am facing a problem that I did not succeed to fix, in this case, I'd like to move the links starting from the middle of the rectangle to put them at the extremity so that PUB-2 and PUB-3 don't cross each other. If possible to expand the first level and close the other by default.

Any idea ? Here is the source code https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 (d3 website) and the working codepen (https://codepen.io/andrea06590/pen/mzJmpE) in which I changed the original circles into rectangles using the code bellow + link spacing on line 126 :

```
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 75)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("x", -10)
      .attr("y", -10)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "red"; });
```

[image: D3 Tree Chart]

Comment: I can fix your lines, but the lines will still be visually overwhelmed by the size of the rectangles; you might want to either try a different visualisation (maybe a sunburst chart?) or use colour to show relationships between elements of the chart. Please post your code here, rather than at an external site, so that it can easily be referenced by other users and so it does not disappear if you delete the codepen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to fix your links:

First, change the rectangle positioning so that they are centred over where the circle would be in the standard link-node diagram. Rather than hard-coding values in the `update` function, I've configured the rectangle dimensions in an object:

```
var rect = {l: 60, w: 20};
```

Edit the rectangle attributes to use the values in `rect`, and centre the rectangle over the node by offsetting the `x` and `y` values by half the length and half the width of the rectangle respectively.

```
nodeEnter.append("rect")
  .attr("width", rect.l)  // long dimension
  .attr("height", rect.w) // short dimension
  .attr("x", -rect.l/2)   // offset by half the long dimension
  .attr("y", -rect.w/2)   // offset by half the short dimension
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "red";
  });
```

To fix the links, we need to change their start and end position by the same offset. Since both exiting and entering links use the position of the source node, the only links we need to worry about are the update selection:

```
link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", diagonal);
```

`diagonal` takes an object of the form

```
{ source: { x: 123, y: 456 }, target: { x: 234, y: 567 } }
```

In the case of the update selection, the data items are already in this configuration, so calling `diagonal(d)` works correctly. Since we're altering the coordinates to include the offset for the rectangle, we have to break out the `diagonal` call. Note that the projection switches the `x` and `y` coordinates, so we have to alter the `y` values:

```
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d){
      return diagonal({
      source: {x: d.source.x, y: d.source.y + rect.l/2}, // add half the rectangle length
      target: {x: d.target.x, y: d.target.y - rect.l/2}  // minus half the rectangle length
    })
  });
```

I also took the liberty of centering the text in the rectangles by removing the offset you'd added and setting the text anchor to 'middle'.

Here's the result:

```js
var pubs =
{
    "name": "AUT-1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "PUB-1","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-11","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-111"},
                    {"name": "AFF-112"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-12","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-121"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-13","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-131"},
                    {"name": "AFF-132"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-14","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-141"}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-2","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-21"},
                {"name": "AUT-22"},
                {"name": "AUT-23"},
                {"name": "AUT-24"},
                {"name": "AUT-25"},
                {"name": "AUT-26"},
                {"name": "AUT-27"},
                {"name": "AUT-28","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-281"},
                    {"name": "AFF-282"},
                    {"name": "AFF-283"},
                    {"name": "AFF-284"},
                    {"name": "AFF-285"},
                    {"name": "AFF-286"}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        {"name": "PUB-3"},
        {
            "name": "PUB-4","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-41"},
                {"name": "AUT-42"},
                {"name": "AUT-43","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-431"},
                    {"name": "AFF-432"},
                    {"name": "AFF-433"},
                    {"name": "AFF-434","children":[
                        {"name": "ADD-4341"},
                        {"name": "ADD-4342"},
                    ]}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-44"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-5","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-51","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-511"},
                    {"name": "AFF-512"},
                    {"name": "AFF-513"},
                    {"name": "AFF-514"},
                    {"name": "AFF-515"},
                    {"name": "AFF-516"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-52"},
                {"name": "AUT-53"},
                {"name": "AUT-54"},
                {"name": "AUT-55","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-551"},
                    {"name": "AFF-552"},
                    {"name": "AFF-553"},
                    {"name": "AFF-554"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-56"},
                {"name": "AUT-57"},
                {"name": "AUT-58"},
                {"name": "AUT-59"},
                {"name": "AUT-591"},
                {"name": "AUT-592"},
                {"name": "AUT-593"},
                {"name": "AUT-594"},
                {"name": "AUT-595"},
                {"name": "AUT-596"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-6","children": [
              {"name": "AUT-61","children":[
                  {"name": "AFF-611"},
                  {"name": "AFF-612"},
                  {"name": "AFF-613"},
                  {"name": "AFF-614","children":[
                      {"name": "ADD-6141"},
                      {"name": "ADD-6142"},
                  ]}
              ]},
              {"name": "AUT-62"},
              {"name": "AUT-63"},
              {"name": "AUT-64"},
              {"name": "AUT-65"},
              {"name": "AUT-66"},
              {"name": "AUT-67"},
              {"name": "AUT-68"},
              {"name": "AUT-69"}
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var diameter = 800;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = diameter,
    height = diameter;
    
var i = 0,
    duration = 350,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1) / a.depth; });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });
          
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width )
    .attr("height", height )
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var rect = {l: 60, w: 20}

root = pubs;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
      links = tree.links(nodes),
      offset = nodes[0].x

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("width", rect.l)
      .attr("height", rect.w)
      .attr("x", -rect.l/2)
      .attr("y", -rect.w/2)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "red";
      });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length * 8.5)  + ")"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

  // nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  //     .attr("r", 4.5)
  //     .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)"; });

  // TODO: appropriate transform
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "diagonal(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  // nodeExit.select("circle")
  //     .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d){
      return diagonal({
      source: {x: d.source.x, y: d.source.y+rect.l/2}, 
      target: {x: d.target.x, y: d.target.y-rect.l/2}
      })
  });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  
  update(d);
}

// Collapse nodes
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

I think that straight lines would look better on this visualisation - e.g.:

```js
var pubs =
{
    "name": "AUT-1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "PUB-1","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-11","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-111"},
                    {"name": "AFF-112"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-12","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-121"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-13","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-131"},
                    {"name": "AFF-132"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-14","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-141"}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-2","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-21"},
                {"name": "AUT-22"},
                {"name": "AUT-23"},
                {"name": "AUT-24"},
                {"name": "AUT-25"},
                {"name": "AUT-26"},
                {"name": "AUT-27"},
                {"name": "AUT-28","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-281"},
                    {"name": "AFF-282"},
                    {"name": "AFF-283"},
                    {"name": "AFF-284"},
                    {"name": "AFF-285"},
                    {"name": "AFF-286"}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        {"name": "PUB-3"},
        {
            "name": "PUB-4","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-41"},
                {"name": "AUT-42"},
                {"name": "AUT-43","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-431"},
                    {"name": "AFF-432"},
                    {"name": "AFF-433"},
                    {"name": "AFF-434","children":[
                        {"name": "ADD-4341"},
                        {"name": "ADD-4342"},
                    ]}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-44"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-5","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-51","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-511"},
                    {"name": "AFF-512"},
                    {"name": "AFF-513"},
                    {"name": "AFF-514"},
                    {"name": "AFF-515"},
                    {"name": "AFF-516"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-52"},
                {"name": "AUT-53"},
                {"name": "AUT-54"},
                {"name": "AUT-55","children":[
                    {"name": "AFF-551"},
                    {"name": "AFF-552"},
                    {"name": "AFF-553"},
                    {"name": "AFF-554"}
                ]},
                {"name": "AUT-56"},
                {"name": "AUT-57"},
                {"name": "AUT-58"},
                {"name": "AUT-59"},
                {"name": "AUT-591"},
                {"name": "AUT-592"},
                {"name": "AUT-593"},
                {"name": "AUT-594"},
                {"name": "AUT-595"},
                {"name": "AUT-596"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PUB-6","children": [
              {"name": "AUT-61","children":[
                  {"name": "AFF-611"},
                  {"name": "AFF-612"},
                  {"name": "AFF-613"},
                  {"name": "AFF-614","children":[
                      {"name": "ADD-6141"},
                      {"name": "ADD-6142"},
                  ]}
              ]},
              {"name": "AUT-62"},
              {"name": "AUT-63"},
              {"name": "AUT-64"},
              {"name": "AUT-65"},
              {"name": "AUT-66"},
              {"name": "AUT-67"},
              {"name": "AUT-68"},
              {"name": "AUT-69"}
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var diameter = 800;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = diameter,
    height = diameter;
    
var i = 0,
    duration = 350,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1) / a.depth; });


var diagonal_extras = {
  path: {
      // diagonal line
      direct: function(p){
        return [ p.source, p.target ];
      }

      // this is also the default path in radial trees
      , l_shape: function(p){
        return [ p.source, { x: p.target.x, y: p.source.y }, p.target ];
      }

      , l_shape_2: function(p){
        return [ p.source, { x: p.source.x, y: p.target.y }, p.target ];
      }

      , dogleg: function(p){
        return [ p.source,
        {   x: p.source.x,
            y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
        },
        {   x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
            y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
        },
        {   x: p.target.x,
            y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
        }, p.target];
      }

      , dogleg_2: function(p){
        return [ p.source,
        {   x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
            y: p.source.y
        },
        {   x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
            y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
        },
        {   x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
            y: p.target.y
        }, p.target];
      }

    }

    , polar_obj_to_cart: function(pt){
        var angle = pt.x / 180 * Math.PI;
        return [pt.y * Math.cos(angle), pt.y * Math.sin(angle)];
    }

    , polar_coords_to_cart: function(xy){
        var angle = xy[0] / 180 * Math.PI;
        return [ xy[1] * Math.cos(angle), xy[1] * Math.sin(angle)];
    }

}

diagonal_extras.right_angle = function() {

      var projection = d3.svg.diagonal().projection()
      , path_type = 'dogleg'
      ;

      function diagonal(d) {
        return diagonal.path_maker( diagonal_extras.path[ diagonal.path_type() ](d) );
      }

      diagonal.path_maker = function( pathData ) {
        return "M" + pathData.map( projection ).join(' ');
      };

      diagonal.valid_path_types = function() {
        return Object.keys( diagonal_extras.path );
      };

      diagonal.path_type = function(x) {
        if (! arguments.length) { return path_type; }
        if ( diagonal_extras.path[ x ] ) {
          path_type = x;
          return diagonal;
        }
        throw new Error( x + ' is not a valid path type' );
      };

      diagonal.projection = function(x) {
        if (!arguments.length) { return projection; }
        projection = x;
        return diagonal;
      };

      diagonal.path = function(x) {
        if (!arguments.length) { return path; }
        path = x;
        return diagonal;
      };

      diagonal.draw = function(d) {
        return diagonal(d);
      };

      return diagonal;
}
diagonal_extras.radial = function() {
      var diagonal = diagonal_extras.right_angle()
      , projection = function(pt){
        return [ pt.x, pt.y ];
      };

      diagonal.path_type('direct');

      diagonal.projection = function(x) {
        if (!arguments.length) { return projection; }
        projection = x;
        return diagonal;
      };

      diagonal.path_maker = function( pathData ) {

        var projected = pathData.map( function(x){ return projection(x); })
        , pl = projected.length
        , points
        , prev_angle
        ;

        // direct link:
        if ( 2 === pl ) {
          return 'M' + projected.map( function(x){ return diagonal_extras.polar_coords_to_cart(x); }).join(' ');
        }

        points = projected.map( function(obj){
          return { angle: obj[0] / 180 * Math.PI, radius: obj[1] };
        });

        return "M" + points.map( function(pt){
          var str = '';
          if ( prev_angle ) {
            if ( prev_angle === pt.angle ) {
              // draw a straight line
              str = 'L';
            }
            else {
              // draw an arc to the new radius and angle
              str = 'A' + pt.radius + ',' + pt.radius
              // x axis rotation
              + " 0 "
              // large arc flag
              + " 0,"
              // sweep
              + ( pt.angle > prev_angle ? 1 : 0) + " ";

            }
          }
          prev_angle = pt.angle;
          return str + pt.radius * Math.cos(pt.angle) + "," + pt.radius * Math.sin(pt.angle);

        }).join(' ');

      };
      return diagonal;
}

var diagonal = diagonal_extras.radial()
  .path_type('dogleg')
  .projection(function(d){ return [ d.x - 90, d.y ]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width )
    .attr("height", height )
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")rotate(90)"); // note the altered rotation

var rect = {l: 60, w: 20}

root = pubs;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

//root.children.forEach(collapse); // start with all children collapsed
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
      links = tree.links(nodes),
      offset = nodes[0].x

  // Normalise angles so that the root is horizontal
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x -= offset;
    if (d.x < 180) { d.x += 360 }
  });
  
  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("width", rect.l)
      .attr("height", rect.w)
      .attr("x", -rect.l/2)
      .attr("y", -rect.w/2)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "red";
      });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return ( d.x < 270 || d.x > 450 )
        ? 'rotate(180)'
        : ''
       });

  // TODO: appropriate transform
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "diagonal(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d){
      return diagonal({
      source: {x: d.source.x, y: d.source.y+rect.l/2}, 
      target: {x: d.target.x, y: d.target.y-rect.l/2}
      })
  });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  
  update(d);
}

// Collapse nodes
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it seems much more understandable with your second snippet. However, if you increase the width, it "does not work" anymore. I've tried different things like modifying your values, but did not succeed, or I don't get the math behind. If we can make these rectangle bigger it would be better as it's dummy text in my example. Bonus would be to have the first element (in the middle) horizontal :) 
https://codepen.io/andrea06590/pen/mzJmpE

Comment: Depending on what text you need to fit into the boxes, you may have to increase the dimensions of the visualisation. You can get a bit of extra space by commenting out the line `nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 80; });` as that artificially constrains the size of the chart; that will allow you to use longer rectangles.

Comment: I've edited the example to show a couple of enhancements.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out, have you received the 50 point ?

Comment: I've seen your codes, but the first one has an error (offset is not defined on line 154), so I took the working changes and put it on my pen, so could you just help me to figure out how to center on the latest saved code ? https://codepen.io/andrea06590/pen/mzJmpE

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to make it "work" using the offset (nodes[0].x) and this code :

```
if (nodes[0].x > 180) {
  nodes[0].x = nodes[0].x - 90
} 
else {
  nodes[0].x = nodes[0].x + 90
}
```

But it is not 100% horizontal in this case

Comment: I apologise for not explaining what I was doing. Basically, you're normalising the `x` values so that the value for the root node is 0 and all the other nodes are relative to that value. `offset` is set to the x value of the chart root, and this line: `nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.x -= offset; if (d.x < 0) { d.x += 360 } });` subtracts the offset from each `x` value. If the resulting value is less than zero, we add 360 to it to ensure we get a positive value.

Comment: Yes indeed, I understood it a bit, but have you seen the first link, the one starting from nodes[0] ? it takes a whole circle and many links are connected to one link. In my version, I have separated links for each children. Can I keep that behavior ?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean -- sorry, I did not realise that was what you wanted to achieve. In that case, it might be better to normalise the values so that the root node is at 180 (i.e. halfway between your min and max, 0 and 360) and then rotate the whole chart so that the root node rectangle is horizontal.

Comment: Yes, I get half of what you wrote, sorry I am french. Does my code looks good or did I miss a condition between 180 and 360 ? I've also tried to say nodes[0].x = 180 but it does not rotate all other nodes. However if i do nodes[0].x = nodes[0].x + 180 it rotates everything.

Comment: Your code looks good for your current layout, but if you want the root rectangle horizontal, you need to make a few adjustments because the whole graph will be rotated, so the text orientation also needs to be altered. I've updated the second example in my answer to show the appropriate graph rotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still not show correct links (see this picture : https://ibb.co/gXDRrz), and here is what I want, in this case I hardcoded the subsctract of 93 to make it almost horizontal for the example : https://ibb.co/hU0xWz
Could you please add this on my last saved codepen ? https://codepen.io/andrea06590/pen/mzJmpE